# CSS file notbe supported with all browsers

Tags: css, web, browser

I´m developing a website with bootstrap4, CSS3, HTML5 but what I've developed and designed isn't supported by different browsers.

Comment: Can you please specify as to what is "not supported"?

Answer (score 1):

There are many things in HTML and CSS which are **Not Supported** or **Partially Supported** by different browsers.

Have a look at https://caniuse.com/ here you can see which things are supported by which browsers.